# Distributed tensorflow with multiple gpu

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

It seems that `tf.train.replica_device_setter` doesn't allow specify gpu which work with.

What I want to do is like below:

```
 with tf.device(
   tf.train.replica_device_setter(
   worker_device='/job:worker:task:%d/gpu:%d' % (deviceindex, gpuindex)):
     <build-some-tf-graph>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your parameters are not sharded, you could do it with a simplified version of `replica_device_setter` like below:

```
def assign_to_device(worker=0, gpu=0, ps_device="/job:ps/task:0/cpu:0"):
    def _assign(op):
        node_def = op if isinstance(op, tf.NodeDef) else op.node_def
        if node_def.op == "Variable":
            return ps_device
        else:
            return "/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:%d" % (worker, gpu)
    return _assign

with tf.device(assign_to_device(1, 2)):
  # this op goes on worker 1 gpu 2
  my_op = tf.ones(())
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check previous versions, but in Tensorflow 1.4/1.5, you can specify devices in `replica_device_setter(worker_device='job:worker/task:%d/gpu:%d' %
                            (FLAGS.task_index, i), cluster=self.cluster)`.

See `tensorflow/python/training/device_setter.py` line 199-202:

`if ps_ops is None:
    # TODO(sherrym): Variables in the LOCAL_VARIABLES collection should not be
    # placed in the parameter server.
    ps_ops = ["Variable", "VariableV2", "VarHandleOp"]`

Thanks to the code provided by @Yaroslav Bulatov, but his protocol is different from `replica_device_setter`, and may fail in some cases.