# How to experiment with placement algorithm in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I'm aware that TF doesn't implement the node placement algorithm they proposed in their whitepaper (yet). TF currently only offers the 'simple_placer'.

If I want to experiment with a different algorithm and cost model, is there a simple way I can implement/test this without recompiling the entire TF and reinstalling it with Pip?

Comment: Just a small clarification: the SimplePlacer is precisely the placement algorithm that was described in the [OSDI paper (Section 3.3)](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi16/osdi16-abadi.pdf). The original [TensorFlow whitepaper (Section 3.2.1)](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) describes an experimental placement algorithm that was never released, and did not achieve results that were as good as the SimplePlacer (plus heuristics like `tf.train.replica_device_setter()`). Finding a good automatic placement algorithm remains a research problem, so good luck!

Comment: @mrry: Thanks, editted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python device setter function to decide where to place nodes during Python graph construction time.

Examples:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991649/419116
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e7508b6efd51f7cfed32ff277e805f8ea60a7a48/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/device_setter_test.py