# Distributed TensorFlow: run multi-gpu on each machine: ran out of memory error occurred

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I'm running [inception distributed training code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). Since the official version only supports single gpu on each machine, I modified the code to use multi-gpu, multi-machines.

After looking into the [Issue 54](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/54#issuecomment-274722215) and [distribute tensorflow with multiple gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991238/distributed-tensorflow-with-multiple-gpu), I found the most convenient way is to treat each gpu as a `worker`, which can be easily implemented with the help of `with tf.device()`. Here I use [ZhuFengdaaa's codes](https://github.com/ZhuFengdaaa/models/commit/57b3afaf7c811c3d13548eab4cedd202add20016#diff-2bbdfc8464d99bf28f8fbf62126fbf50R114) (thanks the author!). The main logic is adding `gpu_id` and using `with tf.device('/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:%d' % (FLAGS.task_id, FLAGS.gpu_id))`.

Specifically, I use two machines: `pc1` and `pc2`, each of which has 4 GPUs (Titan X with 12 GB memory) and use 2 GPUs in each machine, resulting overall 4 workers. I also use those two machines as parameter servers. The TensorFlow version I'm using is `v1.0.0-alpha`. The scripts I used for training are as follows:

```
# run worker_0 on pc1 on GPU 0
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=10 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=0 \
--gpu_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'

# run worker_1 on pc1 on GPU 1
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=10 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=1 \
--gpu_id=1 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'

# run ps_0 on pc1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--job_name='ps' \
--task_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'

# run worker_2 on pc2 on GPU 0
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=10 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=2 \
--gpu_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'

# run worker_3 on pc2 on GPU 1
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=10 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=3 \
--gpu_id=1 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'

# run ps_1 on pc2
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--job_name='ps' \
--task_id=1 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333,pc2:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2001,pc1:2002,pc2:2001,pc2:2002'
```

Then I encountered the following `ran out of memory` error on `worker_1` and `worker_3` and the program crashes:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *********************************************************************************************xxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 128B.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 291, in train
    loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step])
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10,149,149,32]
     [[Node: inception_v3/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:3/gpu:1"](inception_v3/conv0/Conv2D, inception_v3/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/StopGradient)]]
     [[Node: gradients/AddN_86_S4321 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:3/gpu:1", send_device_incarnation=-3559016887808157144, tensor_name="edge_32623_gradients/AddN_86", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'inception_v3/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub', defined at:
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 161, in train
    logits = inception.inference(images, num_classes, for_training=True)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_model.py", line 87, in inference
    scope=scope)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py", line 87, in inception_v3
    scope='conv0')
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/scopes.py", line 155, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/ops.py", line 234, in conv2d
    outputs = batch_norm(conv, **batch_norm_params)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/scopes.py", line 155, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/ops.py", line 114, in batch_norm
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(inputs, axis)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 619, in moments
    y, axes, shift=shift, keep_dims=keep_dims, name=name)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 536, in sufficient_statistics
    m_ss = math_ops.subtract(x, shift)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 372, in subtract
    return gen_math_ops._sub(x, y, name)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 2775, in _sub
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10,149,149,32]
     [[Node: inception_v3/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:3/gpu:1"](inception_v3/conv0/Conv2D, inception_v3/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/StopGradient)]]
     [[Node: gradients/AddN_86_S4321 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:3/gpu:1", send_device_incarnation=-3559016887808157144, tensor_name="edge_32623_gradients/AddN_86", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I checked the usage of GPU memories on each machine using `nvidia-smi`. I found even when I use only one gpu on each machine (in this case, program runs well), all four gpus' memories in each machine are almost fully occupied, i.e. reaching ~12GB. Based on this observation, I wonder the `ran out of memory` error is due to there is not enough space left for running one more worker on each machine. I have tried to make the program uses as much GPU memory based on runtime allocations by setting `sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`, but the error remains.

Could anyone help me on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use cuda visible devices to restrict which worker sees which GPU

Comment: Great! The program runs well now. Thanks a lot! I have another question: although I have set  `sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`, why do I still observe the GPU memory usage is near 100%, no matter what the batch size is? Do I get something wrong?

Comment: I would guess it's WAI, `allow_growth` is not designed to save memory

Comment: But shouldn't small batch size leads to small GPU memory usage?

Comment: only in ideal world. I suspect `allow_growth` grabs new memory from GPU during each step instead of reusing previously allocated memory until the GPU RAM is fully allocated

Comment: Got it! Many thanks for your valuable help!